# Powershell - Need Regex to get folders with number in names

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I'm new in Regex

I have following folder structure:

Directory: C:\Backup\Pictures

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
d-----        22.3.2022.     13:17                2020                                                                                                          
d-----        22.3.2022.     13:17                2021                                                                                                          
d-----        22.3.2022.     13:17                2022                                                                                                          
d-----        22.3.2022.     13:24                archives                                                                                                      
d-----        22.3.2022.     13:18                listing
```

Inside of each folder with year as name i have subfolders which represents months and days, like below:

```
C:\Backup\Pictures\2020\07\24
C:\Backup\Pictures\2020\08\24
C:\Backup\Pictures\2020\09\24
C:\Backup\Pictures\2021\07\24
. . . . .  . . . .  . . .  .
```

I need expression to look only in subfolders with days, for example to look on subfolder 24 in `C:\Backup\Pictures\2020\07\`

I have expression which recognizes if folder name contains 4 numbers but don't know how to expand it to search for 2 subfolders which have 2 digits in name

```
C:\Backup\Pictures\XXXX - done
C:\Backup\Pictures\XXXX\XX\XX - need expression


Get-ChildItem 'C:\Backup\Pictures\' -recurse | where {{ $_.DirectoryName -match '^\d4$' }}
```

But need expression which needs to search folders with following patterns: `C:\Backup\Pictures\4 digits\2 digits\2 digits`

Comment: Would `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Backup\Pictures\20??\??\??` work?

Comment: out of curisosity, how to add rule to check if `20??\??\??` are digits ?

Comment: I posted an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `-Recurse`, simply call `Get-ChildItem` with a wildcard path that resolves to the target paths:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\20[0-9][0-9]\[0-9][0-9]\[0-9][0-9]
```